# Changing login method in MVC

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I built an MVC application that uses username and password for login. Later I decided to use email address instead of username. I changed the required fields in model, login view and controller.

in Login.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Email, new { @placeholder="Email adresi" })
```

in LoginModel

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Mail adresinizi yazınız.")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

in AccountController

```
 var user = userManager.Find(model.Email, model.Password);
```

When i try to login with email and password, it fails. Also i can still login with username and password. Is there any other fields that i need to change?

Comment: Hi Taner OZEL, welcome to StackOverflow! Have you updated the entries in the userManager to contain an email address and password? It seems like you still have the username / password combination on record.

Comment: Thanks DBX12. I thought i did by changing this line in the Login action inside my AccountController ;

var user = userManager.Find(model.Email, model.Password);

Isn't this where we do it?

Comment: Not fully. I'm not certain how your userManager works, but I assume it's an object which access a database of some kind. Let's say the table has two columns "email" and "password". Now if you change the logic for the userManager as you described, you have to rename the columns (which previously were named "username" and "password" from the old login system). Also you have to update the data in the database to hold emails instead of usernames. If an old user in the database had _john.doe_ with password _foo_, you should update to _john.doe@example.org_ with password _foo_.

Comment: So long story short: Is the login data you try to use is actually present in the database?

Comment: Yes, I have both username and password within my database. I can store and access them without any problem.

Comment: Hmm, then I'm clueless. asp.net is not "my" language.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I solved it temporarily by saving email address to username column as well. It works, but i admit, it is not the best practice at all.